# How do i add a value to the first option in my dictionary which has been populated by a query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, data-binding

I am binding a Dictionary resultset to a Dictionary from a query to populate a drop down list but i want to add a default value to the dropdown

I have tried to add the value first and it did not work. I also tried adding it last and reversing it.

```
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Reason" runat="server"  OnInit="ddl_Reason_Init"></asp:DropDownList>           


    protected void ddl_Reason_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlreason = (DropDownList)sender;



        ddlreason.DataSource = sr.ReturnReason();
        ddlreason.DataTextField = "Value";
        ddlreason.DataValueField = "Key";
        ddlreason.DataBind();

        //ddlreason.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Reason--","0"));


    }



               var ddlreasonpop = (from a in pc.tbl_Reason
                            select new { a.Reason, a.Id }).ToDictionary(a => a.Id, a => a.Reason);


        Dic_reason = ddlreasonpop;
        Dic_reason.Add(0, "--Select Reason--");
```

Comment: A Dictionary needs to use a GroupBy that creates keys.pc.tbl_Reason.GroupBy(a => select new { a.Reason, a.Id }).ToDictionary(a => a.Key);  the key will have two properties a.Key.Reason and a.Key.Id

Comment: I don't quite understand. All i want to to do is display the --Select Reason-- at the top of the drop down list because that option is not in the table where the other options come from. i have added code to show where i bind the data to the drop down list

Comment: The take first : ddlreasonpop.First().Key.Reason;